# XUnit Test Web API Assert Status code

Tags: c#, api, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I am new in `XUnit` tests for Web API application. I am trying to make assertion of my response value with the status code 404, but I am not sure how to do so.

Here's my test code.

> Assume the input is null, the test is expected to return NotFound or 404
>   status code.

```
  [Fact]
        public async Task getBooksById_NullInput_Notfound()
        {

            //Arrange
            var mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
            var controller = new BookController(mockConfig.Object);

            //Act
            var response = await controller.GetBooksById(null);

            //Assert
            mockConfig.VerifyAll();

            Assert(response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.NotFound()); //How to achieve this?

        }
```

In the last line of this test method, I am not able to make `response.StatusCode` compile as in the response variable does not have `StatusCode` property. And there is no `HttpStatusCode` class that I can call...

Here's my `GetBooksByID()` method in the controller class.

```
 public class BookController : Controller
    {
        private RepositoryFactory _repositoryFactory = new RepositoryFactory();

        private IConfiguration _configuration;

        public BookController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }



        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/v1/Books/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooksById(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                var response = //bla

                //do something

                if (response == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return new ObjectResult(response);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: It won't compile because `HttpStatusCode.NotFound()` is not a method.  Remove the parenthesis e.g. `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`.

Comment: @Brad thx! It works now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check against returned type

```
// Act
var actualResult = await controller.GetBooksById(null);

// Assert
actualResult.Should().BeOfType<BadRequestResult>();
```

`Should()` and `.BeOfType<T>` are methods from [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) library, which available on Nuget

Comment: My bad, I didnt use `using FluentAssertions;`

Comment: sry, but `NotFound` is not compile, am I missing any other package?

Comment: @Brad, this was an alternative approach to test for expected response, what OP actually tried to do. Seems approach suit OP.

Answer (score 4):

Assert.Equal(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, response.StatusCode);

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but while the accepted answer is valid it pulls in another dependency that's helpful but not required to do this. The most straight forward approach is to reference:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

Then test with:

```
Assert.IsAssignableFrom<NotFoundObjectResult>(response.Result);
```

assuming your method returns an ActionResult.

Answer (score -1):

After getting hints by @Brad, the code compiles and passed the test.

```
 response.ToString().Equals(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```